# Write text file doesnt work java

Tags: java, printwriter, bufferedwriter

This is my project architecture:

[Architecture Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AsJY.png)

I want to write on the file "file.txt", I tried with ***BufferedWriter*** and ***PrintWriter*** but it doesnt work without error.

My code with BufferedWriter :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("FileTLV.txt").getFile());
    try{

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write("I want to write a String");
        writer.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And my code with PrintWriter:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("FileTLV.txt").getFile());
    try{

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.print("I want to print a String");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code execute without any error.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The file is being written, right?

Comment: have you tried using the absolute path of the file instead of simply the file name

Comment: @f1sh the problem is that no text is written to the file

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I can read the contents of the file from the same File object, so I dont think the problem comes from the File object instantiation

Comment: Do you get any exception thrown?

Answer (score 2):

Application resources are read-only.  You cannot write to them.

If you want to override your application resource, write the content to a new location (such as a [temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) or a location somewhere under the user’s home directory), and write some code that checks for that file before falling back on your built-in application resource.

Also, the getFile() method of URL **does not** convert a URL to a valid file name.  It returns the path and query portions of the URL, with all percent-escapes intact, so if you are running from a directory or .jar whose full path contains any characters which are not allowed in URLs, the result will not be usable.  The method should be avoided.  (The method name comes from the fact that java.net.URL was a class present in Java 1.0, and when Java 1.0 was released, most URLs did in fact refer to physical files.)

Comment: Thank you It work. I use the File methode _createTempFile_ to create a temporary file in which I can now write.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/file/Files.html).write from java.nio (Java 7+)

here's an example:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("line1", "line2");
Path file = Paths.get("filename.txt");
Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

And what's really nice:

> "The method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been
>   written (or an I/O error or other runtime exception is thrown)."

```
Files.write(filePathObj, content, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

allows you to append to a file (take a look at the different [OpenOptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html))

In general, Files.nio is really useful, also for reading